# How to create function for query from dataframe Python

Tags: python, function, class

Attempt to create a function by input a search value and the function executes subseting from dataframe with showing a pivot result, which can able to be called from model (class).

```
# sample data
g = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils',
                     'Kings',  'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings',
                     'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
            'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2],
 
            'Year': [2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016,
                     2017, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2017],
 
            'Points': [876, 789, 863, 673, 741, 812, 756, 788,
                       694, 701, 804, 690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = g)
```

**My attempt :**
Same result can be replicated as below but intend to convert it as a class
for repeated usage .

1 - Subset a specific group by value input ,
2 - Return the sum up pivot table

```
df[df['Team'].str.contains("somevalue")].agg(Total=('Points', "sum"))
```

**Goal :**

```
import myfunciton from myclass
myfunction("somevalue")
```

then return the sum up result.

**My problem:**
I don't understand the fundamental of and how to apply a input value into the def comprehensive .
i.e. When to add `return` e.t.c.

```
class myclass :
    def myfunction(conditions) :
        conditions = ["somevalue"]
        df[df['Team'].str.contains(conditions)].agg(Total=('Points', "sum"))
```

Appreciate any explanation provided of practical usage of function if it's not a general thought to create a class in this situation.

Comment: thats not how imports or modules work in python ... you dont need the class at all ... just the function ... and add return and a space right on that last line of you function right before `df[...]`

Comment: That's a very appreciated point-out due to my ignorance of using import or modules . My current usage of a repeated query from a database : `conditions = "somevalue"
        df[df['Team'].str.contains(conditions)].agg(Total=('Points', "sum"))`  , and overwrite somevalue everytime i get a new query . Do you recommend it is already enough ?

Comment: maybe use `icontains` ... but generally yeah